# Handling bad records in Spark after a join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there some tooling in Spark to handle bad records, meaning something which is `null` after a left join or that was not joined properly?

It would be great if there was something like [this](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html) but specifically for checking data quality after joins.

Comment: You can remove rows with null, replace the null with some other value or place all rows with nulls in its own dataframe to do whatever you want. Is this what you are after?

Comment: That is part of the game obviously. But there is no such notion like dead letter queue in spark? For example the databricks link above automatically includes exception file name and some further metadata about the problem

Comment: Also they seem to handle the errors on the go an do not require a second pass over the data just to write the errors.

Comment: nulls after a join are not exactly errors though, it entierly depends on your use-case. In the databricks link, records that do not fit a provided schema are written to a specified file which is a bit different.

Comment: The sad news for you is that some duplicate inserts are not picked up at all in this ecosystem

Comment: Regarding nulls after joins, you are correct, still it would be great if some rules could be specified what constitutes an error and then to apply a common error handling strategy i.e. like for the Databricks stuff to write everything (including exceptions and context) to some file.

Comment: Indeed, like Informatica

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, the reference to Databricks you make is different to the left join (not properly whatever that may mean) situation you mean. I think you also mean outer join at least and that is deliberately so.